# Selecting default value query returns blank

Tags: mysql

I am trying to select the default value if a row do not have a value with this snippet

## 1

```
SELECT IFNULL((SELECT as_title FROM all_scheduled_messages WHERE id = 1 LIMIT 1) ,'lorem ipsum');
```

When i run the query,it returns a blank and so is when i

## 2

```
SELECT as_title FROM all_scheduled_messages WHERE id = 1 LIMIT 1
```

Why is my first query returning the text i want as default?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're going about this all wrong.

You want to wrap `IFNULL` around the actual field.

```
SELECT IFNULL(as_title, 'lorem ipsum') FROM all_scheduled_messages WHERE id = 1 LIMIT 1;
```

However, if you're returning a blank, rather than a `NULL` from your query, `IFNULL` will not work. You'll need to `NULL` the value first:

```
SELECT IFNULL(NULLIF(as_title, ''), 'lorem ipsum') FROM all_scheduled_messages WHERE id = 1 LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: The  query you returns a blank too.

Comment: @user3286430 So you're not checking for `NULL`. Try the second example in the updated answer